# How to handle async calls and transferring information

Tags: java, asynchronous, bukkit

So I'm completely lost on this one, it might be obvious solution or I'm just trying somethin that's not possible but here it is.

I have two classes one is being used as e listener class and second one is the one that handles queue(i will only include relevant code).

Handler class:

```
public void check() {
    for (Queueable queueable : queue) {
        if (!doesReceiverHavePlayers(queueable)) continue;
 
    }
}

private boolean doesReceiverHavePlayers(Queueable queueable) {
    ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
    out.writeUTF("PlayerCount");
    out.writeUTF(queueable.getReceiver());

    Player player = Iterables.getFirst(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers(), null);
    player.sendPluginMessage(plugin, "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());
       
    return /*response*/ > 0;   
}
```

Listener class:

```
@Override
public void onPluginMessageReceived(String channel, @NotNull Player player, byte[] message) {
    if (!channel.equals("BungeeCord")) return;
    ByteArrayDataInput in = ByteStreams.newDataInput(message);
    String subChannel = in.readUTF();

    switch (subChannel) {
        case "PlayerCount":
            int response = in.readInt();

            break;
    }
}
```

The `check` method is called every 5 seconds and `doesReceiverHavePlayers` requests player count from a certain server to see if there are any players on it, but the 'response' arrives in the listener class `onPluginMessageReceived` method. But as you can see I'm trying to use response in the `doesReceiverHavePlayers` method and return boolean value. Is there any way I can achieve this and how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In `onPluginMessageReceived` store the result in a ConcurrentHashMap and then lookup the value in `doesReceiverHavePlayers` instead of making a blocking call.

Something like this:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> playerCounts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

void onPluginMessageReceived() {
    playerCounts.put(subChannel, response);
}


boolean doesReceiverHavePlayers() {
    return playerCounts.get(queueable.getReceiver()) > 0;
}
```